# Security Question: Overwriting Remote Files

Tags: php

I'm writing an administrative panel and I want to store some of the information they enter into a text file for use in a script.  What I don't want is for someone to start accessing those files and changing the data.  The script can be used by any number of my clients so the files need to be secure.

Are files safe from a remote edit?  Is it even possible to overwrite a file remotely (such as with fwrite())?  I'm not concerned about people reading the files (data is publicly viewable), just overwriting or editing them in any way.  If they aren't safe, how can I secure them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out most servers protect against someone using fwrite() from a remote location, so I don't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing data for administration purposes, why would you **not** care if anyone could read them? Surely you wouldn't want one set of clients to read another set of clients data?

> The script can be used by any number
>   of my clients so the files need to be
>   secure.

Your definition of "secure" is vastly wrong.

Why not store the data in a database, allowing clients only to manipulate their own data via the administration panel?

Comment: It isn't personal or secretive data.  In fact the data will get displayed to the users of the scripts.  It's mostly storing text data (for different languages, certain parameters they might want that differ from the defaults, etc), but its all publicly viewable on the actual scripts.

A database is also not the way to go here.  Some of this data needs to be included quite often in the files and creating SQL connections just to receive text data doesn't seem efficient.  That's why I want to store it in text-files.  Reading the files won't harm anything, but editing them in any way can.